# Launching an application with an URI from winform

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, uri

I have a URI that launches a default program and I'm trying to figure out how to launch it from a Windows Form application. All the results on Google are using the Windows Apps API to launch a URI, but I need to do it from a form. How can this be done?

Here is the Apps version:

```
System.Uri uri = new System.Uri("myprotocl://10.0.0.123");
var success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri);
```

Comment: From MSDN I found this [Registering an Application to a URL Protocol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx),hope this help you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming you have a 'handler' registered on your machine for 'myprotocl', you can launch a uri by specifying the uri as the filename of a process.

```
var url = "myprotocl://10.0.0.123";
var psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
psi.UseShellExecute = true;
psi.FileName = url; 
Process.Start(psi);
```