# Can windows forms applications interact with Windows Universal Applications?

Tags: c#, winforms, win-universal-app

I'm currently tasked with writing a windows universal app for a customer, it will need to be called by a third parties existing Windows Form application (they haven't got a universal replacement for it yet).

I need my universal app to be called with a parameter by the windows form application, so that some data is pre-loaded onto a data entry form. Is there a way of doing this, or can windows forms not interact with universal apps?

thanks for your help.
Ryan

Comment: Have you considered [URI Activation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt228339.aspx)?

Comment: UWP apps run in a sandbox that defeats process interop.  A protocol handler is a backdoor but it is one-way and you cannot get your app certified if you use it.  There are gritty options when you side-load, the way you intend to distribute is a detail you cannot omit from a question like this.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be able to do this by using *URI* protocol.

First what you will have to do is to register your application *URI* scheme and handle its activation - help and samples you [will find at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt228339.aspx).

Second thing is to open the protocol in *WPF* app - you will find help at [this question at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21977231/2681948).

Some help you can also find [here at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Please Refer to [App services sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/AppServices).

You can provide a service (background task) in your UWP, then other app (win32 or UWP) can consume and communicate with UWP.